# Dreamforce 2016 DevZone Call for Presentations is Live!

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

If you have a topic that you've been eager to share with your peers, the [Dreamforce 2016 DevZone Call for Presentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/dreamforce-2016-devzone-call-presentations-live.html) is open until the end of May.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I saw something about this yesterday but then couldn't find it again, thanks for the heads up!